# REST with Spring Controller issue

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I've my rest uri's as below

1. `/leagues` - Lists all the leagues organized so far
2. `/leagues/{leagueName}` - Details of the give `leagueName`
3. `/leagues/{leagueName}/levels/` - Lists all the levels of a given league (For e.g. Playoffs, QF, SF etc)

**Controllers**

1.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/leagues", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String list(Model model)
{
    return "/leagues/list";
}
```

2.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/leagues/{leagueName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String leagues(@PathVariable String leagueName, Model model)
{
    return "/leagues/league";
}
```

3.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/leagues/{leagueName}/levels", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String levels(@PathVariable ("leagueName") String leagueName, Model model)
{       
    return "/leagues/levels/list";
}
```

The problem I am having is that the controller method for the (2) `/leagues/{leagueName}` is being invoked when I try (2) `/leagues/levels/`. Need help on how to fix this.

Comment: can you share how the controllers are declared - its syntax and request mappings

Comment: @ArunPJohny added the mappings

Comment: Look at your mappings. There is nothing else it could possibly map that path to. Did you mean to access `/leagues/myleague/levels/` maybe?

Comment: I don't think there is a framework level support to filter out certain pathvariable value... so you may have to handle the value internally inside the `levels` method

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add the leguname to the url: use `/leagues/SuperHero/levels/` instead (`/leagues/levels/`)

---

If you want to filter out /leagues/levels/`, then you can try to add an additional handler method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/leagues/levels/")
```

for example, to return all levels of any league

Comment: If add this new mapping, how can spring differentiate between '/leagues/SuperHero' and '/leagues/levels'?

Comment: Did Spring seperate between them?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is perfectly fine... The URL leagues/levels matches the second method's RequestMapping...

If you want to invoke the third method u need the URL as leagues/[some string]/levels